# Rails - Validation :if one condition is true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

On Rails 5.

I have an `Order` model with a `description` attribute. I only want to validate it's presence if one of two conditions is met: if the current step is equal to the first step OR if require_validation is equal to true.

I can easily validate based on one condition like this:

```
validates :description, presence: true, if: :first_step?

def first_step?
 current_step == steps.first
end
```

but I am not sure how to go about adding another condition and validating if one or the other is true.

something like:

```
validates :description, presence: true, if: :first_step? || :require_validation
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can use a lambda for the `if:` clause and do an or condition.

```
validates :description, presence: true, if: -> {current_step == steps.first || require_validation}
```

Comment: Beautiful solution.

Answer (score 16):

Can you just wrap it in one method? According to the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates)

> :if - Specifies a method, proc or string to call to determine if the validation should occur (e.g. if: :allow_validation, or if: Proc.new { |user| user.signup_step > 2 }). The method, proc or string should return or evaluate to a true or false value.

```
validates :description, presence: true, if: :some_validation_check

def some_validation_check
    first_step? || require_validation
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a lambda to be evaluated as the `if` condition.

Try:

```
validates :description, presence: true, if: -> { first_step? || require_validation }
```

Comment: Isn't that a lambda? A block would be: `validates :description, presence: true, if: { first_step? || require_validation }`

Comment: Ah, you are right. I should have said "You can pass a lambda".

Comment: :) A block also works though. Rails just converts it to a proc or lambda (I forget what) before using it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add one method as Jared say then you can try use lambda

```
validates :description, presence: true, if: ->{ first_step? || require_validation }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot case , you can design for validates

```
validates_presence_of :price_tech_fee, if: :price_tech_fee_require?, :message => :required

validates_presence_of :percentage_tech_fee, if: :percentage_tech_fee_require?, :message => :required

def percentage_tech_fee_require?
    is_active? && is_transaction_percentage? && is_premium?
  end

def is_active?
  !self.is_deleted && self.is_active
end

def is_transaction_percentage?
 self.is_per_transaction && self.is_percentage
end

def is_premium?
  ....
end
```

Comment: Convention says that you shouldn't define a method that is called "is_,,," if it should return a boolean value. Just use "?" at the end (like you did).