# Ruby on Rails validating uniqueness on other column presence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

How to validate uniqueness in model based on if other column has value or not, not on actual content? Scope seems to compare the content of the second column. For example I have in my User model columns email and project_id (both string) among others. I want to validate email to be unique if project_id is null or has any value. Using scope allows creating objects {email: 'a@a.a', project_id: nil}, {email: 'a@a.a', project_id: '1'}, {email: 'a@a.a', project_id: '2'} and so on. I want to limit the email uniqueness so that those first two objects would be possible (project_id is nil or 1 with same email) and last object would throw error 'email has already been taken' because there's already user with same email when project_id has value. Is there proper rails way to achieve that or do I need to write some custom validation?

Of course I have better email validation also and wouldn't accept 'a@a.a', that's just an example :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails - Validation :if one condition is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42495133/rails-validation-if-one-condition-is-true)

Comment: Not exactly because that just validates presence if conditions are met. I need to validate unique always depending on other column presence. Basically one email would be allowed max 2 times and either project_id is nil or has any value.

Comment: I think the easiest thing here would be to have an "empty" project which serves the purpose of your project_id evaluating to nil. That way you can just use a standard scope on your uniqueness validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope option in uniqueness validation is not the same as a Rails scope. It's more related to SQL and is generally restricted to just an attribute names.

So, since you can't use custom scope in uniqueness validation, you have to write custom validation for this purpose.

```
validate :validate_email_on_project_id_existence  

def validate_email_on_project_id_existence
  if User.where(email: self.email).where(self.project_id.nil? ? 'project_id IS NULL' : 'project_id IS NOT NULL').first
    errors.add(:email, "some error")
  end
end
```

Comment: I was pretty sure that custom validation is the only choice and this code is even more cleaner than what I came up with :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom validation and call it with [validates_with](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validates-with), in your case it'd be something like:

```
class ExampleEmailUniqueness < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    error_message = "has already been taken"
    if record.project_id.nil? && Example.where(project_id: nil, email: record.email).exists?
      record.errors.add :email, error_message
    elsif Example.where(email: record.email).where.not(project_id: nil).exists?
      record.errors.add :email, error_message
    end
  end
end

class Example < ApplicationRecord
  validates_with ExampleEmailUniqueness
end
```

That validation against your scenario would yield the results:

```
Example.new(email: 'a@a.a').save                  # Saved
Example.new(email: 'a@a.a', project_id: '1').save # Saved
Example.new(email: 'a@a.a', project_id: '2').save # Email has already been taken
Example.new(email: 'a@a.a').save                  # Email has already been taken
```

Note that saving a model with a nil project_id AFTER saving one that isn't nil will still pass validation and get saved to the database, which I'm not sure if it's the intended behavior.

Comment: Rather than `empty?` which will instantiate all the Example objects use `exists?` which will run a simple EXISTS query and return a boolean value without loading the objects into memory e.g. `Example.where(project_id: nil, email: record.email).exists?`

Comment: @engineersmnky you're right, I edited my code to use `if exists?` instead of `unless empty?` and reduced it to a single `if-elsif` statement, so now it looks cleaner as well